# Which memory is used for variables defined globally?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Suppose we need to work with 8MB stack, and wish to use standard C++ arrays.
Is it true, that

```
const int MX = 10000;
int DP[MX][MX];

int main() {
  printf("%likB\n", (sizeof(DP))>>10);
}
```

uses heap memory, and for that reason does not segfault (as opposed to when `DP` is declared in `main`)? Is it different from allocating the memory via `new` / `malloc` in `main` (besides `free` issues)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In modern OS's, the memory used by an executable is split into (usually) five  distinct sections:

- The Code section (also known as `text` in Linux/Unix systems for <strike>hysterical</strike>historical reasons). This is where your functions "live". Often also used for constant values, such as `char *s = "Hello, World";`, the "Hello, World!" part is stored in the CODE section.
- The "Initialized" data section (also known as "data") - for global (in C and C++ terms static) data that has been given a value, e.g. `int x = 42;`
- Uninitialized data, also known as BSS, Block Storage section - for global data that is not given a value, and thus initialized to zero. `int y;` in a global context, or `static int status;` would fall into this section.

All of the above sections are defined in the executable. Some executables have more sections than this, but these are the "typical" ones. An example of an "extra" section is a "read-only data" section, which may be used to store for example string data, rather than storing it in the "code" section.

Once the executable is loaded, two more sections are created by the OS:

- A stack, which is used to hold local variables inside functions, and is also used to "get back" to the calling function. The stack is commonly fairly restricted in size, but nowhere near as small as it used to be - these days, the stack is regularly in the "a few megabytes" size range. My first machine I used, had a stack of 256 bytes (and that was hard-coded). If you wanted more than that, you had to arrange that by making your own software defined stack. Not very pleasant!
- A heap. This is used for "dynamic allocation" - for example when creating storage for arrays that vary in size depending on program input. The contents of the heap is not known before the program has started to run. In modern systems, the heap starts out with a small size, and is allowed to grow (but there is a limit, if nothing else when the machine itself runs out of memory - but often the limit may be lower than that from a system configuration, to avoid one application using up all of the memory in the machine).

In the above example, `DP` is in the "uninitialized data" section.

Answer (score 1):

It will use [static memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_memory_allocation) to store `DP` and it is *basically* the same as dynamically allocating with `new`/`malloc()`, without the need to manage the memory.

Comment: No it won't! It uses static storage ("zero initialized data segment", BSS, or what you want to call it) , which is different from heap or stack.

Answer (score 1):

It uses global memory, not heap memory, and is preallocated on startup by the OS. Since it isn't local to a function, the size of the stack is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, user memory is divided into three sections: heap, stack and static(including const).
Typically a global variable is in the static section. Since the memory of an array is allocated when it is defined, I believe it's also in static section.
Besides, I can't find any article about allocating a global array in heap. If someone find it otherwise, please give me an @.